# save .properties file beside class

Tags: java

I want to save `config.properties` file beside `Prefs.java` . I tried do it like this but it says `java.io.FileNotFoundException`  :

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("myPackage/config.properties");
```

my Project structure is:
`+ myPackage`
`- Prefs.java`

How to save `config.properties` beside `Prefs.java` like this:

`+ myPackage`
`- Prefs.java`
`- config.properties`

Comment: Try using `OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("myPackage/config.properties"));` That will create a new File if it does not exist.

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh Yes, but not where amir wants it: on top level, rather than in `mypackage/` It also does not do anything different than what amir already has.

Comment: If you rely on a path (like your "myPackage"), you also assume your code runs in a certain directory, which may or may not be the case. If you get the `FileNotFoundException`, chances are you are not running where you think you are. I'd recommend using an absolute path (e.g., `~/.yourProgram` on Unix or `C:\Users\...` on Windows) to a well-known location to save your program's settings. Or check if there is a library to save settings which you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could find a way to access `config.properties` file beside class,
here is the code which i could rich that file:

```
File f = new File("");
File config = new File(f.getAbsolutePath()+"/src/qrCode/config.properties");
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(config);
```